# API call results in "undefined" return

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, api, return

Based on the JavaScript below, I am using Ajax to call specific data via an API. It's authenticated using a username and a password.

I can see the data I need in the console, title and macro_address, but when it hits the HTML page, it shows me:

> Job: undefined, Location: undefined

Why?

```
$(function () {
    var $jobs = $('#jobs');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://url.com/api/api-key/jobs?status=active',
        username: 'user name',
        password: 'password',
        beforeSend: function (req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
        },
        success: function (jobs) {
            $.each(jobs, function (i, prem) {
                $jobs.append('<li> Job ' + prem.title + ', Location: ' + prem.macro_address + ' </li>');

            });
        }
    });
```

Within the HTML document, I have a simple ul called #jobs. Also, if it's helpful, here is a raw sample of the JSON at the API endpoint:

```
    {
{
"current_page":1,
"total_pages":1,
"per_page":25,
"total_count":5,
"results":[
{

"id":00001,
"title":"Job title goes here",
"macro_address":"New York, NY",
"created_at":"2016-07-22T20:54:52.526Z",
"published_at":"2016-07-22T20:54:52.526Z"},
```

This is the jQuery dist I'm using:
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js

Comment: It's pretty tough to tell but I would put `console.log(jobs)` right below the `success: function (jobs) {` line and check what it says in the [console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/).. you can use Ctrl+Shift+J (Windows / Linux) or Cmd+Opt+J (Mac).

Comment: Hey thanks for your comment. I did add that and nothing changed. The array info is still visible in the console but the output is still "undefined".

Comment: It sounds like you're literally getting nothing from your API.. I would check the code for your API and make sure it is really sending data

Answer (score 0):

Made a little progress here.I got the API to return some results, but now it's returning multiple instances of the same object in the array. In this case, I'm telling it to call only the 4th object in the Array. I'm still working on it and will post if I solve on my own.

```
    $(function () {
    var $jobs = $('#jobs');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://url.com/api/api-key/jobs?status=active',
        username: 'user name',
        password: 'password',
        beforeSend: function (req) {
            req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('username:password'));
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, jobs) {
                $jobs.append('<li> Job: ' + data.results[4].title + '</li>');

            });
        }
    });
});
```

[image]